# QGridLayout not resized nor repainted when child widgets get hidden

Tags: c++, qt

I have a widget with `QVBoxLayout` as the main layout and `QGridLayout` as a child layout nested inside the main one. There is toggle button which shows/hides certain widgets in the grid layout. After updating visibility I want to adjust (minimize) the size of the widget. But resizing does not work correctly when child widgets get hidden, the widget size stays the same, it is not shrinked as I would expect. Moreover the widget is not correctly repainted, some bad button fragments remain visible. I observed that this does not happen if the grid layout is the main one (i.e. there is no vertical layout), but if it is nested inside another layout it behaves strange. Any ideas how to fix this?

widget.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <QWidget>

class QGridLayout;
class QPushButton;

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
private:
    void updateVisibility();
    QGridLayout *m_layout;
    QPushButton *m_button;
};
```

widget.cpp:

```
#include "widget.h"

#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    m_layout = new QGridLayout();
    m_layout->addWidget(new QLabel("Label1"), 0, 0);
    m_layout->addWidget(new QLabel("Label2"), 1, 0);

    m_button = new QPushButton("Visible");
    connect(m_button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Widget::updateVisibility);
    m_button->setCheckable(true);
    m_button->setChecked(false);

    auto layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    layout->addLayout(m_layout);
    layout->addWidget(m_button);
    updateVisibility();
}

void Widget::updateVisibility()
{
    // hide or show Label2
    m_layout->itemAtPosition(1, 0)->widget()->setVisible(m_button->isChecked());
    adjustSize();
}
```

Before:

[image]

After clicking 2 times on the button:

[image]

UPDATE: I reported this as a bug https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-66151 but I would like to find a suitable workaround until it is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot reproduce on Xubuntu 16.04.3 with Qt 5.5.1 or Qt 5.9.4. I do observe some strange behavior though. If I add `Widget` to a `QMainWindow` and check the button, it ignores the mainwindow's layout until the mainwindow is resized.
If I use `Widget` as a top-level window, it becomes larger on the first click, and then never resizes again, unless the user changes the window size.

Possible workarounds:

- Remove the `adjustSize()` call, that prevented my strange behavior.
- Call `update()` on widget or it's parent after `adjustSize()` to schedule a redraw. (Cannot test since I have no drawing artefacts.)
- Call `m_layout->invalidate()` after `adjustSize()` to schedule re-layouting. Fixes my problem when inside the mainwindow. You can also try that call on the widget's parent, or before `adjustSize()`.

Comment: I tried several combinations and what worked was `m_layout->invalidate()` being called BEFORE (rather than after) `adjustSize()`. If you update your answer with this option, I will accept it because you deserve it for your effort.

Comment: Ok, that is really weird.. Updated as requested :-)

Comment: In my case I had a QHBoxLayout inside QGridLayout and it didn't resize as expected. Struggling with this for a couple of hours.... adjustSize() did the trick! Thanks You both very much!